# Dynamically update Object in state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to dynamically update the values I get from a form. I have a form that has different pages.

```
interface EndResultType {
        [key: string]: string;
}
```

That's why I created a state called `endResult`, I will initialize this object with every element I want at the end (as empty string).

For a nicer looking code example I removed some values from it.

```
let [endResult, setEndResult] = useState<EndResultType>({
        object_category: '',
        object_type:     '',
        offer_type:      ''
});
```

For each submission of a form I want to load the values into the `endResult` state.

```
function onFormSubmit(event: React.SyntheticEvent): void {
    event.preventDefault();
     try {
        const relevantKeys = Object.keys(endResult);
        for (let key of relevantKeys) {
            // @ts-ignore
            const value = event.target[key].value;
            console.log('Key: ' + key);
            console.log('Value: ' + value);
            setEndResult({
                ...endResult,
                [key]: value,
            });
        }
        console.log(endResult);
        // post('/?module=api', )
        setPage(page + 1);
    }
    catch (err) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.error(err);
    }
```

Since I'm using `...endResult` I assumed that the values I receive from the target get updated in the state. But they aren't. I have tried debugging and validated that I receive the correct values and keys from the target.

[image: Console log]

My assumption is that `[key]: value` is not working how I hoped / assumed it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to consider:

- the setter of `useState` is asynchronous, console logging the value right after calling it will always log the old value
- the setter of `useState` is batched, meaning calling it multiple times like in your loop, will only take the last value into consideration, overwriting the previous set calls

To fix those issues, you could create a "result" object, add the values to it, and then set the object to state at the end, like so:

```
function onFormSubmit(event: React.SyntheticEvent): void {
  event.preventDefault();

  try {
    const relevantKeys = Object.keys(endResult);
    const result = {...endResult};

    for (let key of relevantKeys) {
      // @ts-ignore
      const value = event.target[key].value;
      console.log("Key: " + key);
      console.log("Value: " + value);
      result[key] = value;
    }
    // post('/?module=api', )
    setPage(page + 1);
    setEndResult(result);
  } catch (err) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

The next time React re-renders your component, it will have the correct value in the state.